# how to prohibit loading USB device with VID and PID using wdk

Tags: usb, wdk

How to prohibit loading USB device with VID and PID using wdk.

I want prohibit accessing USB storage with specified VID and PID.

How to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I had seen : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065473/find-and-eject-a-usb-device-based-on-its-vid-pid

Comment: and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14500/Detecting-Hardware-Insertion-and-or-Removal